# Symfony3 MongoDB service error

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am trying to set up Symfony3 with MongoDB by following this tutorial: [Symfony3 Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

I followed everything right through and after Persist Object to MongoDb Chapter i reloaded my page and get this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function get() on null
```

If i underst it right it means that the get method cannot find the declared service?

my Controller code:

```
    <?php

namespace Cambio\CambioBundle\Controller;

use Cambio\CambioBundle\Document\Product;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $product = new Product();
        $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
        $product->setPrice('19.99');

        $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        $dm->persist($product);
        $dm->flush();

        return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());
    }
}
```

and this is my config.yml:

```
# MongoDB Configuration
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

Not quiet sure what is the problem and how i can fix it.

Additional Errol Logs:

```
in src/Cambio/CambioBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php at line 18   -
        $product->setPrice('19.99');
//        $m = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection');
        $dm = $this->container->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection')->getManager();
        $dm->persist($product);
        $dm->flush();
```

and Log:

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Error: Call to a member function get() on null" at /Users/Tomazi/Dev/SymfMongo/src/Cambio/CambioBundle/Controller/AuthenticationController.php line 18
```

More edits:

OK so i go this working previously my Controller was defined as service and this set up did not work as soon as i added new Controller and did not declare it as service every magically works:

Routing.yml:

```
    cambio_test:
    path:     /test
    defaults: { _controller: CambioBundle:Default:index }

cambio_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: cambio.authentication.controller:loginAction }
```

Services.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>

        <!-- Controller -->
        <service id="cambio.authentication.controller"
                 class="Cambio\CambioBundle\Controller\AuthenticationController">
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

and the Default controller has the same code init it any idea why it does not work when Controllers is decleared as a service but it does work when controller isynt defined as one...?

Comment: You need to look at log files to find out where that error exactly occurs.

Comment: Please provide provide tracelog of the exception. There is only one `get` function in the code snippet, and obviously `$this` is not `null`.

Comment: Hey Hopefully my edit can help you guys have closer look at what is going on

Comment: Can you please show the routing configuration for your login action?

Comment: Well, it is a bit different thing, isn't it? Apparently `$this->conteiner` is slightly uninitialized. It is not related to mongodb, but rather how you define and use your controller.

Comment: Sorry for making this post so long but can you guys have a look at my new edits. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are using wrong service name. In the [linked documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#using-the-abstraction-layer) they are using something else:

```
$m = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection');
```